# How to select next item in list

Tags: c#

I have a list of IPAddresses `List<IPAddress> proxies;` and a current proxy `IPAddress CProxy;`. I'm adding each line in a proxy txt file to the list and having it be used for httprequests. each time the request fails it adds 1 to `int ProxyRetries`.

```
            if (ProxyRetries > 5)
        {
            ProxyRetries = 0;
            CProxy = proxies // how to select next proxy in the list?
        }
```

My question is how can i set the current proxy to be the next in line of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int current = 0;

CProxy = proxies[current];
current++;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<IPAddress> proxies;
    IPAddress CProxy;
    int iProxy = 0;

    if (ProxyRetries > 5)
    {
        ProxyRetries = 0;
        CProxy = proxies[iProxy++]
    }
```